# Django HTMLCalendar

Tags: django

[image]I am first time using HTMLCalendar to render calendar for my application, however I am not getting last day of the month shown e.g. June 2023 only shows days from 1 to 29 but not 30. What is wrong in my below code?

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        try:
            # Get all events that start on this day
            events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)

            # Get all events that span across this day
            events_spanning = events.filter(start_time__lt=datetime.datetime(self.year, self.month, day+1),
                                            end_time__gt=datetime.datetime(self.year, self.month, day))

            d = ''
            if events_spanning:
                # Render all spanning events in a row
                d += '<div>'
                for event in events_spanning:
                    d += f'<div class="border rounded p-1 mb-1 bg-hover">{event.get_html_url}</div>'
                    # Exclude this event from the events_per_day list
                    events_per_day = events_per_day.exclude(id=event.id)
                d += '</div>'

            # Render all other events for this day
            for event in events_per_day:
                d += f'<div>{event.get_html_url}</div>'

            if day != 0:
                if datetime.datetime(self.year, self.month, day).weekday() in \[5, 6\]: # add class for weekends
                    return f"<td class='weekend'><span class='date my-text'><a href='{reverse('add_event')}' type='button' class='pt-1 btn-shape-weekend text-decoration-none align-middle' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='left' data-bs-title='Click to record time'>{day}</a></span><div class='day'> {d} </div>"
                elif date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                    return f"<td class='current-day'><span class='date my-text'>{day}</span><div class='day'> {d} </div>"
                else:
                    return f"<td><span class='date my-text'><a href='' type='button' class='pt-1 btn-shape text-decoration-none align-middle' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-placement='left' data-bs-title='Click to record time'>{day}</a></span><div class='day'> {d} </div></td>"
            return '<td class="empty-day"></td>'
        except ValueError:
            # Handle the "day is out of range for month" error
            return '<td class="empty-day"></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        cal +=f'</table>' 
        return cal][1]][1]
```

attached is screenshot showing June 2023 month which is missing 30th of June. Could someone look and advise how I can address the issue?

Comment: Is there any HTML output for the 30th at all, eg, is it coming up as an 'empty day' as those have no date in them?